# Proving a Jacobi-like identity with four elements in a Lie algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

Let ${\frak g}$ be a Lie algebra. Then $$  [[[X,Y],Z],W] +[[[Y,X],W],Z]+[[[Z,W],X],Y]+[[[W,Z],Y],X]=0 $$for all $X,Y,Z,W \in {\frak g}$.

---

I started using the Jacobi identity four times to get: 
\begin{align} [[X,Y],Z]+[[Y,Z],X]+[[Z,X],Y] &= 0 \\ [[Y,X],W]+[[X,W],Y]+[[W,Y],X] &= 0 \\ [[Z,W],X]+[[W,X],Z]+[[X,Z],W] &= 0 \\ [[W,Z],Y]+[[Z,Y],W]+[[Y,W],Z] &= 0 \end{align}

Then I apply $[\cdot, W]$ to the first equality, $[\cdot, Z]$ to the second, $[\cdot, Y]$ to the third and $[\cdot, X]$ to the last one to get

\begin{align}
\color{blue}{[[[X,Y],Z],W]}+[[[Y,Z],X],W]+[[[Z,X],Y],W] &= 0 \\ \color{blue}{[[[Y,X],W],Z]}+[[[X,W],Y],Z]+[[[W,Y],X],Z] &= 0 \\ \color{blue}{[[[Z,W],X],Y]}+[[[W,X],Z],Y]+[[[X,Z],W],Y] &= 0 \\ \color{blue}{[[[W,Z],Y],X]}+[[[Z,Y],W],X]+[[[Y,W],Z],X] &= 0
\end{align}

Summing, we get what we want (in blue), plus some crap consisting of eight terms, equaling zero. I don't know what to do to see that the crap is zero. Help?

Comment: This identity is true iff it's true with the brackets interpreted as commutators, at least over a field of characteristic zero; this is a corollary of the PBW theorem applied to free Lie algebras.

Comment: Never heard of that result. I'll look it up, but this exercise is in chapter 1 of the book, so I'm not supposed to use big guns...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate additional identities using the Jacobi identity for $T = [X,Y], Z$, and $W$ and for $S = [Z,W], X$, and $Y$:
$$
\begin{align*}
0 & = [[T,Z],W] + [[W,T],Z] + [[Z,W],T]  \\
& = [[[X,Y],Z],W] + [[W,[X,Y]],Z] + [[Z,W],[X,Y]]\\
0 & = [[S,X],Y] + [[Y,S],X] + [[X,Y],S] \\
& = [[[Z,W],X],Y] + [[Y,[Z,W]],X] + [[X,Y],[Z,W]]
\end{align*}
$$
Using anticommutativity twice on the second terms lets us rewrite these in the following form:
$$
[[[X,Y],Z],W] + [[[Y,X],W],Z] + [[Z,W],[X,Y]]=0\\
[[[Z,W],X],Y] + [[[W,Z],Y],X] + [[X,Y],[W,Z]]=0
$$
Adding these together gives you the desired relation (again using anticommutativity).

(You can use this method to show that the eight remaining terms you mention add to zero as well.)

Comment: Thanks. But can you elaborate a bit more on how you got the first extra identity? I don't follow it. From using anticommutativity onwards I'm good.

Comment: Ah! It was straightforward, my bad. Thanks again.

Comment: @IvoTerek You're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

I want to add an additional reference, which also contains a proof, but also shows how to generalise such Jacobi-like identities. It is the paper [Jacobi - type identities in algebras and superalgebras](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1304.5050v2.pdf). The identity for $n=4$ is given in $(5.3)$, on page $9$.