# question regarding Jacobi's identity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am struggling with understanding the Jacobi identity (I am using it for matrix's commutator).

Let $[A,B] = AB - BA$. Then the following is true

$[A,[B,C]] + [B,[C,A]] + [C,[A,B]] = 0$

Also the following is true

$[A,B] + [B,A] = 0$

But increasing the number of matrices I never got any identity..

$[A,[B,[C,D]]] + [B,[C,[D,A]]] + [C,[D,[A,B]]] + [D,[A,[B,C]]] \ne 0$

$[A,[B,[C,[D,E]]]] + [B,[C,[D,[E,A]]]] + [C,[D,[E,[A,B]]]] + [D,[E,[A,[B,C]]]] + [E,[D,[A,[B,C]]]] \ne 0$

Why is it true only when three matrices are involved?

Comment: It will be true for more than three matrices, but one has to apply the Leibniz rule for derivations. See for example [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1785756/proving-a-jacobi-like-identity-with-four-elements-in-a-lie-algebra): $$  [[[X,Y],Z],W] +[[[Y,X],W],Z]+[[[Z,W],X],Y]+[[[W,Z],Y],X]=0 $$

Comment: Thank you. I will take a look at the post. I thought it's just one of those obvious equations, but I was wrong. thank you